# Getting first instance of a date from otherwise identical rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which there are multiple rows that are essentially identical, except for a timestamp. There will be many permutations of a, b, and c, but I need only the earliest timestamp of them.

Now I know that I *can* do this programatically after loading the whole set into memory and processing, but I feel like there is possible a native way to do this in SQL and that might be more efficient. I want to know if it is possible to do this purely in SQL.

For the sake of a concrete example, here's a simplified version below. I'm just going to put a year in the timestamp field for the sake of brevity in the example.

```
id | a | b | c | timestamp
1  | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2018
2  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2016
3  | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2017
4  | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2010
5  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2018
```

In this example I would need to end up with rows 2, 4, and 5.

For reference, I'm using MySQL and PHP. I've already processed in a large number of records programatically, but I have a few dozen more record sets to go. While the solution I have is working where I load them all, and then iterate through to capture the earliest record, I would really like to learn if a pure SQL solution is possible.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Do you need the `id` too, or just `a`, `b`, `c` and the timestamp?

Comment: Also, what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I would need the whole row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Group by` with [Min()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) function on the timestamp.

Try the following:

```
SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c, MIN(t.timestamp) as timestamp 
FROM your_table AS t 
GROUP BY t.a, t.b, t.c
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use a `where` clause and correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.timestamp = (select min(t2.timestamp)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.a = t.a and t2.b = t.b and t2.c = t.c
                    );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(a, b, c, timestamp)`.